# The jekyll-sass-converter is apparently not accepting Sass comments?

Tags: sass, comments, jekyll

I added two lines of triple dashes to the top of a scss file, triggering jekyll to process the file (ruby version 3.2.1, jekyll version 4.3.2, jekyll-sass-converter version 3.0.0).

Tracing the output of a "bundle exec jekyll serve" command, it became apparent that both styles of sass comments

- leading `//`
- enclosing `/*  */`

are generating syntax errors. Is it intended that sass comments not be supported by jekyll?

I initially had some comments in a sass file. It kept failing until I removed them, then worked fine.

Is there perhaps an option that can be set to allow sass comments?